# Link in a Bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read that it may be impossible but I still need to be sure about inserting a link to a local file in the bootstrap navbar. Here is my navbar:

[image]

I'd like the Home Icon ( on the left ) to redirect to my home file while the links on the right redirect to other parts of the page. But nothing happens when I click. I'm desesperate for help so i'm waiting for you guys to enlight my day :)
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
  <title>Helpy.</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #818181;
  }
  h2 {
      font-size: 24px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }  
  .jumbotron {
      background-color: #f4511e;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 100px 25px;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .container-fluid {
      padding: 60px 50px;
  }
  .bg-grey {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
  .logo-small {
      color: #f4511e;
      font-size: 50px;
  }
  .logo {
      color: #f4511e;
      font-size: 200px;
  }
  .thumbnail {
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
  }
  .thumbnail img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
      background-image: none;
      color: #f4511e;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
      border-color: #f4511e;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li.active {
      background-color: #f4511e;
  }
  .item h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: italic;
      margin: 70px 0;
  }
  .item span {
      font-style: normal;
  }
  .panel {
      border: 1px solid #f4511e; 
      border-radius:0 !important;
      transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  .panel:hover {
      box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  }
  .panel-footer .btn:hover {
      border: 1px solid #f4511e;
      background-color: #fff !important;
      color: #f4511e;
  }
  .panel-heading {
      color: #fff !important;
      background-color: #f4511e !important;
      padding: 25px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .panel-footer {
      background-color: white !important;
  }
  .panel-footer h3 {
      font-size: 32px;
  }
  .panel-footer h4 {
      color: #aaa;
      font-size: 14px;
  }
  .panel-footer .btn {
      margin: 15px 0;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      z-index: 9999;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a:not(#top) {
      color: #f4511e !important;
      background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  footer .glyphicon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      color: #f4511e;
  }
  .slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
  .slide {
      animation-name: slide;
      -webkit-animation-name: slide;    
      animation-duration: 1s;   
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      visibility: visible;          
  }
  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }   
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 150px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" id="top" style="background-color: #f4511e;" href="home.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home logo-extrasmall"></span></a>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Helpy.</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SOLUTIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">DONATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a  id="top" style="background-color: #f4511e;" href="#myPage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up logo-extrasmall"></span></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please narrow your code to only the area in question.

Comment: Done :) thanks for telling me

Comment: Is your boostrap header in the root directory?

Comment: and is your page called home.html?

Comment: I think it is but I'm not really sure

Comment: Yes the file is called home.html

Comment: works fine https://jsfiddle.net/omooaurc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your smooth scrolling function like this :

```
$(".navbar a:not(.navbar-brand), footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
```

Comment: Looks like i'm kind of stupid with an answer like this, I don't know a lot about these scripts so thank you a LOOOOOOOT ! thanks !

Comment: It worked, This site is great and you, smdsgn, are the best.

Comment: Un francais en plus :)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith he has updated his code to narrow  only the area in question, but he removed the js part...where the error was.

Comment: If this question is answered then mark it as so please.

Comment: How ? Sorry, it's my first question